# What happens when you assign 2 variables to a function?

Tags: python, oop

I recently started learning what OOP is and how to start coding in Python. Unfortunately, i'm still a novice and im stuck with understanding some code.

```
def feed(state, size):
  size += 1
  print("Fish fed")
  if size == 5:
    state = "FISH"
  return state, size


thisFishState = "Fish"
thisFishSize = 1
print(thisFishState, "is of size", thisFishSize)
while thisFishState != "FISH":
  thisFishState, thisFishSize = feed(thisFishState, thisFishSize)

print("It is now a big", thisFishState)
```

i was told to write my own edition of this code (i was given the pseudocode) and i wrote this

```
def Feed(State, Size):
  size += 1
  print("Fish fed")
  if size == 5:
    state = "FISH"
  return State, Size


thisFishState = "Fish"
thisFishSize = 1
print(thisFishState, "is of size", thisFishSize)
while thisFishState != "FISH":
 feed(thisFishState, thisFishSize)

print("It is now a big ", thisFishState)
```

however my code doesnt give the same output as the original. Why?
What is the purpose of assigning 2 variables to a function? What does it do? And if you can explain, could you explain in the simplest way possible?

Comment: What are you calling "assigning two variables to a function"? Are you referring to using tuple unpacking to assign the output of a function to two separate variables? (That's backwards from what the question describes).

Comment: the first code says "thisFishState, thisFishSize = feed(thisFishState, thisFishSize)" whereas mine simply calls the function "Feed" and that little part is confusing me

Comment: For one thing: `Feed != feed`, `Size != size`, and `State != state`; in python case matters

Comment: Okay -- that is indeed tuple unpacking. The linked duplicates should help you -- see them shown up at the top of the question.

Comment: many many thanks
and i didnt notice that little typo, thank you :)

Comment: @G.Anderson: The first two will be obvious errors at least. The fact that `State != state` is worse, because they use both in such a way that the `if size == 5: state = "FISH"` is effectively never going to happen (because `state` is assigned and ignored, and the unchanged `State` is what gets returned). Regardless, all of them should be lower case, per [PEP 8's naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), since none of them are classes (the only case for the CapWords shown is class names and `typing` alias types, neither of which occur here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is an inconsistency in your code. In the function declaration, you've used `Feed` (uppercase F) but later in the code, you make a call to `feed` (lowercase f). Fix this!

Note that your are assigning two variables to **the return value(s) of the function**, not to the function itself. To answer your question, the function `Feed` returns two values (`State` and `Size`). The following line simply unpacks them:

```py
thisFishState, thisFishSize = feed(thisFishState, thisFishSize)
```

In other words, `thisFishState` is set to the first value returned from `Feed` (i.e. `State`), and `thisFishSize` is set to the second value (i.e. `Size`).

In your code, you simply make the call to `feed` without saving or using it's value anywhere:

```py
feed(thisFishState, thisFishSize)
```

What your code's missing is this:

```py
thisFishState, thisFishSize = feed(thisFishState, thisFishSize)
```

See [this page](https://blog.tecladocode.com/destructuring-in-python/) about destructuring in python for more info. Also, please look up camelcase! :-)

Comment: if i understood correctly, "setting the variable" or "tuple unpacking" returns the variables without the need of a return? and camelcasing is using Capitals for only Classes?"You should only use StudlyCaps for class names." But this was amazing, you explained this code so much better than my teacher :D

Comment: The reason I mentioned camelcase is because it is the most common naming convention when using Python, and choosing one is very important! It does not necessarily have to be camelcase, but just pick one and stick to it. If you mix multiple naming conventions, you'll have a hard time remembering if you named your variable myVariable, MyVariable, my_variable or My_Variable etc, plus it makes the code easier to read and understand, for you and for others, if you stick to one naming convention. Check this page out for more: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/ Good luck!